# Find duplicates in jquery array using unique

Tags: jquery

I have the following JS arrays.

```
$arrTest1 = ['46819', '46819', '46819'];
$arrTest2 = ['46819', '46802', '46819'];

let len1 = arrTest1.length;
let len2 = $.unique(arrTest1).length; 

if (len1 > len2) {
  alert('Found duplicate');
} else {
  alert('Did not find duplicate');
}


let len3 = arrTest2.length;
let len4 = $.unique(arrTest2).length; 

if (len3 > len4) {
  alert('Found duplicate');
} else {
  alert('Did not find duplicate');
}
```

For first array $arrTest1 its working and showing found duplicate but for $arrTest2 its showing as Did not find duplicate. Did I missed something?

$.unique is not working for $arrTest2 whereas for $arrTest1 it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

1. `$.merge()` is used to combine `array1` and `array2` into `combinedArray`.
2. `$.grep()` is used to filter `combinedArray` and find the duplicate values, which are stored in `duplicateValues`.

#### Refer below Code

```js
$arrTest1 = ['46819', '46819', '46819'];
$arrTest2 = ['46819', '46802', '46819'];

const combinedArray = $.merge($.merge([], $arrTest1), $arrTest2);

// Find duplicate values
const duplicateValues = $.grep(combinedArray, function (element, index) {
  return index !== $.inArray(element, combinedArray);
});

if(duplicateValues.length) {
  alert('Found duplicate');
} else {
  alert('Did not find duplicate');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is not the goal of OP, he need to know if in `arrTest1` and `arrTest2` exist some duplicate value

Comment: Right so we can check `duplicateValues` this is empty or not same case right?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I have updated more specific code with if statement.

Comment: See my answer (work perfect with Set).

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation:](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.unique/)

> Description: Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the
> duplicates removed. **Note that this only works on arrays of DOM**
> **elements, not strings or numbers**.

```js
$arrTest1 = ['46819', '46819', '46819'];
$arrTest2 = ['46819', '46802', '46819'];

let len1 = $arrTest1.length;
let len2 = [...new Set($arrTest1)].length; 

if (len1 > len2) {
  alert('Found duplicate');
} else {
  alert('Did not find duplicate');
}


let len3 = $arrTest2.length;
let len4 = [...new Set($arrTest2)].length; 

if (len3 > len4) {
  alert('Found duplicate');
} else {
  alert('Did not find duplicate');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) like my example

Answer (score 0):

`$.unique` has be removed in `V.3.0` and above you can do it using `$.grep()`

```js
var arrTest1 = ['46819', '46819', '46819'];
var arrTest2 = ['46819', '46802', '46819'];

var duplicatesTest1 = $.grep(arrTest1, function (e, i) {
    return $.inArray(e, arrTest1) !== i;
});

if (duplicatesTest1.length > 0) {
    alert('Found duplicate in arrTest1');
} else {
    alert('Did not find duplicate in arrTest1');
}

var duplicatesTest2 = $.grep(arrTest2, function (e, i) {
    return $.inArray(e, arrTest2) !== i;
});

if (duplicatesTest2.length > 0) {
    alert('Found duplicate in arrTest2');
} else {
    alert('Did not find duplicate in arrTest2');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```